# vs code esp-idf unresolved import from standard c library windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, esp-idf

C:\Users\Lasse\esp\esp-idf\examples\get-started\blink.vscode\settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "idf.portWin": "COM3",
    "idf.flashType": "UART",
    "files.associations": {
        "sdkconfig.h": "c"
    },
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": ""
}
```

C:\Users\Lasse\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "idf.espIdfPathWin": "C:\\Users\\Lasse\\esp\\esp-idf",
    "idf.pythonBinPathWin": "c:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\python_env\\idf4.2_py3.8_env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "idf.customExtraPaths": "C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\esp-2020r3-8.4.0\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\\esp-2020r3-8.4.0\\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\esp32ulp-elf\\2.28.51-esp-20191205\\esp32ulp-elf-binutils\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\esp32s2ulp-elf\\2.28.51-esp-20191205\\esp32s2ulp-elf-binutils\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\cmake\\3.16.4\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\openocd-esp32\\v0.10.0-esp32-20200709\\openocd-esp32\\bin;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\ninja\\1.10.0;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\idf-exe\\1.0.1;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\ccache\\3.7;C:\\Users\\Lasse\\.espressif\\tools\\dfu-util\\0.9\\dfu-util-0.9-win64",
    "idf.customExtraVars": "{\"OPENOCD_SCRIPTS\":\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Lasse\\\\.espressif\\\\tools\\\\openocd-esp32\\\\v0.10.0-esp32-20200709/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts\",\"IDF_CCACHE_ENABLE\":\"1\"}",
    "idf.portWin": "COM3",
    "idf.port": "/dev/ttyUSB3",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:\\Users\\Lasse\\esp\\**"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"
}
```

"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser" - line helped to solve non std library imports

C:\Users\Lasse\esp\esp-idf\examples\get-started\blink.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\**",
                
                "C:\\Users\\Lasse\\esp\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

[image: Still having issue finding <stdio.h>]

I think this could have something to do with missing

```
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": ""
```

Where is the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

This video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRyvly_SYS8 (From 10:18 to 14:34).

I resolved the include errors by following this procedure. Press F1, then select C/C++ Edit configurations (UI).

**Include Path:**

Reference: https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/issues/26#issue-556057077

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
${env:IDF_PATH}/components/**
build/config
```

**Compiler path:**

Check https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/issues/27#issuecomment-580165821

**IntelliSense mode:**

Choose gcc-x64(legacy)

Answer (score 0):

Add compile_commands.json to your `c_cpp_properties.json`

`"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"`